# Contact form php not send email

Tags: php, contact-form

I have a contact.HTML file with follow code:

```
<div>
    <form id="email-form" name="email-form" action="mail.php" data-name="Email Form">
        <input class="w-input text-field" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your full name" name="name">
        <input class="w-input text-field" id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address">
        <input class="w-input text-field" id="phone" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Enter your telephone number">
        <textarea class="w-input text-area" id="text-area" name="message" required placeholder="Your message here..."></textarea>
        <div class="div-spc">
            <button class="w-button button no-margin" type="submit">Submit Message</button>
        </div>
    </form>
  <div id="result"></div>
</div>
```

and a file mail.php with follow code:

```
<?php    
define( "RECIPIENT_NAME", "Site name" );
define( "RECIPIENT_EMAIL", "xxx@domainame.com" );

$success = false;
$senderName = isset( $_POST['name'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\' a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['name'] ) : "";
$senderEmail = isset( $_POST['email'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\_\@a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['email'] ) : "";
$phone = isset( $_POST['phone'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\' a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['phone'] ) : "";
$message = isset( $_POST['message'] ) ? preg_replace( "/(From:|To:|BCC:|CC:|Subject:|Content-Type:)/", "", $_POST['message'] ) : "";

if ( $senderName && $senderEmail && $message ) {
  $recipient = RECIPIENT_NAME . " <" . RECIPIENT_EMAIL . ">";
  $headers = "From: " . $senderName . " <" . $senderEmail . ">";
  $success = mail( $recipient, $message, $headers );
  echo "<p class='success'>Mail Sent!</p>";
}    
?>
```

The form doesn't work... and I have message `email sent` on my page on the browser.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: Dose your server support mail() ?

Comment: yes server support mail()

Answer (score 0):

Mail sending needs SMTP settings. Please check them correctly.

Also, your code checks if form variables are posted or not.

It does not check whether the mail is sent or not.

Change your code to:

```
$recipient = RECIPIENT_NAME . " <" . RECIPIENT_EMAIL . ">";
$headers = "From: " . $senderName . " <" . $senderEmail . ">";
$success = mail( $recipient, $message, $headers );
if ($success) {
 echo "<p class='success'>Mail Sent!</p>";
}
```

Comment: where i need to change?

Comment: Change the if condition as I posted in my answer.

Comment: <?php

define( "RECIPIENT_NAME", "Site name" );
define( "RECIPIENT_EMAIL", "email@address.com" );

$recipient = RECIPIENT_NAME . " <" . RECIPIENT_EMAIL . ">";
$headers = "From: " . $senderName . " <" . $senderEmail . ">";
$success = mail( $recipient, $message, $headers );
if ($success) {
 echo "<p class='success'>Mail Sent!</p>";
}

?>